# Injecting Spring Spel Expressions into bean properties

Tags: spring, spring-el

How can I inject a String meant to be a spel expression into an app context bean property without having the context interpret the string property as a spel resolvable value.

`<bean id="x" p:spelExpression="${#code}/${#value}"/>`

I want the the class's setter property to take a string argument and creates a reusable SpelExpression as a private property of the bean, however, the spring application context appears to be recognizing the #variableName as spel expressions and attempting to interpret the expression at initialization time.

I find Spel interpretation to be very useful, but would like to to use spel internally as well, with expression injection into my own beans.

Is it possible to disable the Spel Interpretation of for a bean, or even for a whole context file (maybe with some namespace shenanigans) without having to disable or modify spel expression resolution for the whole application context.

Answer (score 0):

The #{...} are markers for spel interpreter in xml context.

I don't undestand : `${#code}/${#value}`. Good is `#{code/value}`, as I understand things, if *code* and *value* are id.

So, if you want a spel expression without interpret it, put string `code/value` in xml.

Comment: This question really doesn't have anything to do with XML. I want to be able to create a bean in an application context that makes use of a SPEl expression.I don't want the spel expression to be interpretted by the application context. It is for the bean to use. For example, the bean would create an Expression and then iterate a collection a call expression.getValue(currentCollectionItem) in loop.

Comment: I don't understand : You say it's not XML, and I see a XML text in your question ? If there is no xml, but only String, put string spel expression... In your exemple, it's `code/value`, or perhaps `@code/@value`, depends on what are `code` and `value`. Perhaps provide some code (no xml ? ) ?

Comment: *It's not xml it's a template parser context to generate a string. An alternative example is a URL path, e.g code=x,value=y would generate the string 'x/y'. The point of the question is still how to inject the string expression into a bean and not have it be interpreted by the app context as a evaluated spel expression.

Comment: Again I don't understand, sorry :-) If you have a bean, with a string property, and you do `myBean.setMySpelExpression("fooAndMore")`, it is NOT interpreted by anything.

Comment: The trick comes trying to emulate myBean.setMySpelExpression("${#code}/${#value}") using the application context xml. e.g. <bean id="myBean" class="..." p:mySpelExpression="${#code}/${#value}"/>. The spring context tries to interpret the property value for you using SpEL. You can shut of spel interpretation for an entire context, but I was hoping for a more targeted solution.